# MFC- Open a dialog box on a button click

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a standard mfc(not dialog based) application in visual 2012. My task is to open a dialog box on button click in the toolbar. The dialog box takes some parameter and update the data in drawing window. How can I do this ?
I am trying the following approach, I edit the resource file and add a new dialog box and design it according my requirements. Now i create a class attached with the dialog box through the class wizard but whenever i try to include that class to the projectview class it gives the following error.

**Error 1   error C2065: 'IDD_ABOUTBOX' : undeclared identifier c:\users\khan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\graph\graph\cdiog.h 15**

I have tried to change the id of the dialog box but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Include "resource.h" file.

Comment: Thanks but tell me another way around it. My task is to open a dialog box on toolbar button click. the dialog box should contain some edit boxes for input data and drawing canvas needs to be updated according the data. The problem i am facing is how to call the dialog box from the handler of the button.

Comment: Why should there be another way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ defines the IDs like IDD_ABOUTBOX in the resource.h file. First check to make sure it is in there. Then you must #include "resource.h" where it will be read before your dialogname.h file is read. So you can do the #include at the top of dialogname.h, or you can do it in your viewname.cpp file if that #include comes before the #include of dialogname.h.